# Faking a Angular Factory in a directive in jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

Question: How do I fake my pointFactory so I can Jasmine Unit Test it.

I have the Following Directive.
It takes the html sends it to a factory and the uses the response for some logic

```
CommonDirectives.directive('TextEnrichment',['PointFactory','appSettings', function (pointFactory,settings) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
         var text = element.html();
         pointFactory.getPoints(text).then(function(response){

 })}}}]);
```

So far my unit tests looks like this, however it doesn't work since I'm not injecting the factory.

```
beforeEach(module('app.common.directives'));

beforeEach(function () {
    fakeFactory = {
        getPoints: function () {
            deferred = q.defer();
            deferred.resolve({data:
                [{"Text":"Some text"}]
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
getPointsSpy = spyOn(fakeFactory, 'getPoints')
        getPointsSpy.andCallThrough();

 });

beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_,_$controller_){
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

it('Factory to have been Called', function () {
    var element = $compile('<div data-text-enrichment=""> Text </div>')($rootScope)
    expect(getPointsSpy.callCount).toBe('1');
});
```

### Update

Following advice from Felipe Skinner I have updated the test with the following

```
  beforeEach(function(){
       module(function($provide){
           $provide.factory('PointFactory',getPointsSpy)
       })
});
```

However I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'pointFactory.getPoints(text)')

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $provide to inject your controller dependencies.
Here's my beforeEach for example:

```
describe('MyCtrl', function() {
    var $controller,
        $scope,
        $httpBackend,
        windowMock,
        registerHtmlServiceMock,
        mixPanelServiceMock,
        toastMock;

    beforeEach(function() {
        windowMock =  { navigator: {} };
        registerHtmlServiceMock = {};
        mixPanelServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('mixpanel', ['track']);
        toastMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('toast', ['error']);

        module('myModule');
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('$window', windowMock);
            $provide.value('RegisterHtmlService', registerHtmlServiceMock);
            $provide.value('MixPanelService', mixPanelServiceMock);
            $provide.value('ToastService', toastMock);
        });

        inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $controller = _$controller_('CourseSelectionCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });
    });

    // my test cases

});
```

I haven't tried mocking a function that returns some value. Those two mocks (mixpanel-track and toast-error) are for "void" functions.

**UPDATE:**

Try changing the previous $provide with this type of injection then.

Change from this:

```
module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('$window', windowMock);
    $provide.value('RegisterHtmlService', registerHtmlServiceMock);
    $provide.value('MixPanelService', mixPanelServiceMock);
});

inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_('CourseSelectionCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
});
```

To this:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
        mixPanelService = mixPanelServiceMock;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_('MyCtrl', { $scope: $scope, MixPanelService: mixPanelService });
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));
```

The rest of the code should be the same, except for that. Let me know if this works

Comment: Hello,

I Updated my Question with the results of your suggestion and I got function undefined for pointFactory.getPoints()

Comment: I have updated my Answer with another approach for the injection. Hope that works

Comment: Notice that I used the "jasmine.createSpyObj('mixpanel', ['track']);" to mock my method call... I didn't create the object by myself like you did with "fakeFactory = {getPoints function()}". Try using jasmine.createSpyObj to mock it.